# error while testing dynamic route in nextjs using post man

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I have written a next api route using file name as route.ts and I wrote 2 routes one for getting all users in data base and one for only getting one user passing a user id as query through params my folder structure and codes of the routes are given below while i am tesing my routes in post man the route for getting all users is working fine and while i am running the dynamic route by passing id i am receiving all users instead of the user whoose id i sent i have used prisma for querying how to solve this

code for fetching one user

```
import {  NextResponse } from "next/server";
import prisma from '@/libs/prismadb'
import { NextApiRequest } from "next";



export  async function GET(
    req:NextApiRequest,
    
){
    if(req.method!=='GET')
    {
        return NextResponse.json({"message":"something went wrong","status":400});
    }

    try {
        const users = await prisma.user.findMany({
            orderBy:{
                createdAt:'desc'
            }
        })

         return NextResponse.json({"message":users,"status":200});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
         return NextResponse.json({"message":"something went wrong","status":400});
    } 
}
```

code for fetching all users

```
[![My Folder Strucutre][1]][1]
```

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import prisma from '@/libs/prismadb'
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export  async function GET(
    req:NextApiRequest,
    res:NextApiResponse
)
{
    try {
        const {userId} = req.query

        if(!userId || typeof userId!=='string')
        {
            throw new Error("Some Thing Went Wrong")
        }

        const existingUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where:{
                id:userId
            }
        })

        NextResponse.json({"message":existingUser,"Status":200})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        NextResponse.json(error)
    }

}
```

Comment: hey there, can you please add the file names and the folder structure to your question?

Answer (score 1):

The code for fetching one user is actually using `findMany`, which will fetch all users, and the code for fetching all users seems to be designed for fetching one user by ID.

Here's the snippet for getting all users:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import prisma from '@/libs/prismadb';

export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest) {
  if (req.method !== 'GET') {
    return NextResponse.json({ "message": "something went wrong", "status": 400 });
  }

  try {
    const users = await prisma.user.findMany({
      orderBy: {
        createdAt: 'desc'
      }
    });

    return NextResponse.json({ "message": users, "status": 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return NextResponse.json({ "message": "something went wrong", "status": 400 });
  }
}
```

And, here's the snippet for getting one user

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import prisma from '@/libs/prismadb';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  try {
    const { userId } = req.query;

    if (!userId || typeof userId !== 'string') {
      throw new Error("Something Went Wrong");
    }

    const existingUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: parseInt(userId),
      },
    });

    res.json({ "message": existingUser, "Status": 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.json(error);
  }
}
```